# ESP32 stops reading RFID tag after amount of time

Tags: c, wifi, esp32

I've been working on a clock-in, clock-out system for my employees. It is supposed to connect to WiFi and when scanned with a tag, uploads the current time to my database online.

Point is, I've been testing it randomly and it has been working great. No problems whatsoever but then when I leave it for a few hours, I scan the tag but nothing happens. It seems to have frozen in some way.

The code is relatively simple, I connect to Wifi and when a tag is presented, make a http request and produce a beep to notify a succesful scan.

The code (removed info as of security reasons):

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

// WiFi credentials and server details
const char* ssid = "-BV";
const char* password = "";
const char* serverName = "";
String apiKeyValue = "tPmAT5Ab3j7F9";
String sensorName = "RFID";
String sensorLocation = "Office";

// RFID reader pins
#define SS_PIN  5  // ESP32 pin GPIO5 for RFID-RC522
#define RST_PIN 27 // ESP32 pin GPIO27 for RFID-RC522
MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create MFRC522 instance

const int biepPin = 25;

int count = 0;

WiFiClientSecure client; // Create a global WiFiClientSecure instance

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("\nConnected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522
  Serial.println("RFID reader initialized");

  pinMode(biepPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      Serial.println("RFID tag detected");
      String uidString = "";
      for (byte i = 0; i < rfid.uid.size; i++) {
        uidString += String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "") + String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
      }
      uidString.toUpperCase();

      client.setInsecure(); // Set the client as insecure
      HTTPClient https;
      https.begin(client, serverName);
      https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      
      String httpRequestData = "api_key=" + apiKeyValue + "&sensor=" + sensorName
                            + "&location=" + sensorLocation + "&value1=" + uidString;
      Serial.println("Sending HTTP request");
      int httpResponseCode = https.POST(httpRequestData);
      
      tone(biepPin, 1000); 
      delay(100);           
      noTone(biepPin);    

      delay(50);             

      // Second tone (lower frequency)
      tone(biepPin, 800);
      delay(100);    
      noTone(biepPin);    

      if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
        Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
        Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      }
      else {
        Serial.print("Error code: ");
        Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      }
      https.end();
      rfid.PICC_HaltA(); // Halt PICC
      rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1(); // Stop encryption on PCD
    }
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
  }
  count = count++;
  Serial.println(count);
}
```

Comment: We may need to see more of your Wifi code. In `loop`, if status is _not_ `WL_CONNECTED`, you [silently] do nothing. This would appear as a hang. So, if the interface disconnects (Wifi can be fragile), where are you reconnecting? I'd add some debug `printf`.

Comment: I see, how can I make it less fragile? There is no more WiFi code, this is everything

Comment: As I mentioned, if `.status` is "wrong", then `loop` does nothing. I'd add some code that monitors `.status` and prints a message (to serial or logfile, etc.) that shows the change in state (e.g.) `void loop(void) { static int oldstat = -1; int newstat = Wifi.status();  if (newstat != oldstat) { printf("%s: loop: NEWSTATUS %d\n",timestamp(),newstat); oldstat = newstat; }  if (newstat == WL_CONNECTED) { ... } }` Then, we know if wifi drops and/or reconnects (or _not_). After that, it _may_ be necessary to reinit [some] things.

Comment: There are other calls (e.g. `PICC_IsNewCardPresent` and `PICC_ReadCardSerial`) that could be monitored similarly. For a robust server/client, it must check for (and recover from) devices/interfaces having errors.